Why are my tables being left-justified?
Previously, I had added something to left justify my tables and captions, but now wish for them to be centered. I removed a section of code concerning the "captions" package and my captions are centered now, but the tables remain left-justified. What is causing this?
Preamble:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[indent=20pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\Large#1\end{center}
   }%
}
\newcommand{\subsubtitle}[1]{%
  \preauthor{%
    \begin{center}
    \large #1 \vskip0.5em
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    }%
}
\newcommand{\buffer}
{\hspace{0.2cm}}
\newcommand{\rational}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\extraline}{\vspace{2mm}}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ \left(\mathrm{mod}\ #1\right)}
\newcommand{\asin}{\sin^{-1}}
\newcommand{\deriv}{\mathrm{d}}
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={7in, 9.5in},margin=1in]{geometry}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\title{xxww}
\subtitle{wwxx}
\date{}
\author{}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[R]{\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

Table:
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    $d$ (m) & $\omega_1$ & $\omega_2$\\
\hline
        25 & 39.29 & 4.45\\
        30 & 40.61 & 2.36\\
        50 & 37.31 & 0.61\\
        60 & 37.01 & 0.51\\
        75 & 36.70 & x\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Average Experimental angular velocities}
\label{tab:omegaavg}
\end{table}


you have provided no usable example but \begin{table} sets up a float that is taken out of the document flow to be re-inserted elsewhere so by design it does not inherit the current font and alignment it resets to the document defaults.

Welcome to TeX.SE!
Instead of two code fragments you should provide on small but complete document which reproduce your problem. To it all packages loaded in your preamble are not relevant to table, so you can drop them out.
If you like that you table be horizontally centered, you must tell this to LaTeX:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering   % <--- added for centering of table
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    $d$ (m) & $\omega_1$ & $\omega_2$\\
\hline
        25 & 39.29 & 4.45\\
        30 & 40.61 & 2.36\\
        50 & 37.31 & 0.61\\
        60 & 37.01 & 0.51\\
        75 & 36.70 & x\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Average Experimental angular velocities}
\label{tab:omegaavg}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Without \centering instruction table will on page be left aligned.

D'oh, for some reason I thought that figures and tables were normally centered, and it was something in my preamble messing it up. Thanks!

If answer solve your problem, you may consider to accept them, (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)
